# Style empty option of a <select> in print to hide it

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My `<select>` tags contain a default option with a prompt for the user, for example:

```
<option value="">Select a country...</option>
```

If the user fails to select anything, I want to hide "Select a country" in print.

Here's what I've tried:

```
@media print {
option[value=''] {
    color: transparent !important;
    width: 1px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 1px;
    text-indent: -100px;
    opacity: 0;
}
}
```

None of this works.

Other topics here on StackOverflow about styling individual `<option>`s is possible if you assign a class to that particular option.

I did so (the class had a `display:none` rule) but that didn't help either.

Is there a CSS-only way to hide `<select>`s with an empty option selected in print?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "If the user fails to select anything"..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Choose..</option>
  <option>First option</option>
  <option>Second option</option>
</select>
```

To hide from print:

```css
@media print {
  select option[disabled] {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Choose</option>
  <option value="first">First option</option>
  <option value="second">Second option</option>
</select>
```